# how to click ion-tabs when use protractor for e2e test

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, protractor, e2e-testing

I tried lots of ways but still have problem with that.
This is my tabs.html

```
<ion-tab class="tab1" [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Forum"    tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab class="tab2" [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Chat"     tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab class="tab3" [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="MyOLLE"   tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
```

This is my 1st tabs.e2e-spec.ts

```
var chat = element(by.tagName('ion-tab[tabTitle="Chat"]')).getWebElement();
browser.actions().mouseMove(chat).click().perform();
browser.sleep(6000);
```

The problem of above code is that it actually didn't go to the chat page when runing the test.

My 2nd test

```
var chat = element(by.tagName('ion-tab[tabTitle="Chat"]'));
chat.click();
```

This will tell me

> Failed: element not visible

Can anyone tell me how can I click the tab or how can I redirect to the page I want?

Comment: @alecxe Can you please help me about this problem?

Comment: are you sure that your element is visible? Maybe you should wait before clicking on it?

Comment: @Oleksii  Thanks for advice. It runs ok on ionic serve and tabs are visible. And I'm not quite sure how to do the wait method. I tried once and it always told me timeout. Could you please give me some examples or advice?

Comment: If it is protractor with jasmine you can try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each tab of ionic has an **id**. You can see it if you open dev tools.
To navigate to the tab I have created this method:

```
import {element, by} from 'protractor';

navigateToTab(tabName: 'Forum' | 'Chat' | 'MyOLLE') {
    let id;
    switch(tabName) {
        case 'Forum':
            id = 'tab-t0-0';
        break;
        case 'Chat':
            id = 'tab-t0-1';
        break;
        case 'MyOLLE':
            id = 'tab-t0-2';
        break;
    }
    return element(by.id(id)).getWebElement().click();
}
```

Hope it helps. If you have questions let me know

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Although I've solved this problem with same way, your structure is better and thanks again for your help. And would you mind answer me another question relate to E2E for ionic? That is how can i test the ion-datetime? I can't directly use sendkeys to set the time.

Comment: It is possible. Look at this example https://github.com/vlio20/angular-datepicker/blob/master/e2e/move-to-date-api-e2e.spec.ts

Answer (score 0):

If it is protractor with jasmine you can try this

`element(by.className('.tab2')).click();`

or

```
get chatTab() {return $(.tab2);}
// This is the normal 
// Page Object
// Model
public chatClick()
{
chatTab().click();
}
```